# Connection Errors whit MSSQL over PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, xampp

i`d like to use a simple SQL-Statment in a small .php.
but my problem is i cannot conect to the server (MSSQL 2014)

Error:
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: localhost\SQLEXPRESS in

Code:

```
<?php

$verbindung = mssql_connect('localhost\SQLEXPRESS', '*****', '*****');

if (!$verbindung || !mssql_select_db('php', $verbindung)) {
die('Connection Failed');
}
?>
```

My System:
i use a XAMPP-Server 1.7.0 whit PHP 5.2.8

Thx 4 u help :)

(spelling errors you may keep ;P)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to connect to the server using another method?

Comment: i tryed almost the same 1 week ago whit a php 5.5 + but you need to use MYSQLI functions (#bugged as crap)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape the slash:

```
$verbindung = mssql_connect('localhost\\SQLEXPRESS', '*****', '*****');
```

Comment: Then I would check the driver you are using. Newest drivers can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: witch one i`ll need?

Answer (score 0):

Got it :D

```
$user = '*****';
$pass = '******';
$server = 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS';
$database = 'Account';


$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database"; 
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);

if ($conn) {
      echo "Connection established.";
     } else{
die("Connection could not be established.");
    }
```